# ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table class_1(column1,column2)
```

while inserting values

```
INSERT INTO class_1 (column1, column2, [Section]) 
VALUES(1, 'First')
```

> Erorr: SQL Error: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
>   01747. 00000 -  "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"

Comment: `[Section]` is an invalid identifier. You can't use `[` or `]` in an identifier in SQL. See the chapter "Basic Elements of Oracle SQL" in the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223

Answer (score 0):

the table name is different in insert statement from class1 to class_1

```
INSERT INTO class1 (column1, column2, [Section]) 
VALUES(1, 'First', 'A')
```

Comment: `[Section]` is an invalid identifier in SQL (and in Oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Error:

> SQL Error: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Description of error:
The table is created with only 2 columns. However, while inserting, `[Section]` is considered as a new column. Due to this, column `class_1.[Section]` is not available is thrown as ORA-01747 error.